# Creating DTS package in SQL server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, dts

I am using below script to create DTS package and it is working fine on SQL 2000 but its failing on the first step "failed to create package..." on SQL Server 2008 R2. please help if someone knows the answer

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'Ole Automation Procedures', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

actual query

```
print 'creating a DTS package'

DECLARE @objPackage int
DECLARE @returnValue int
EXEC @returnValue = sp_OACreate 'DTS.Package', @objPackage output
IF @returnValue <> 0
BEGIN
    raiserror('failed to create package returnValue = %d', 16, -1, @returnValue)
    return
END
EXEC @returnValue = sp_OAMethod @objPackage, 'LoadFromStorageFile' , null,
    @UncFile = @FileName, @password = null
IF @returnValue <> 0
BEGIN
    raiserror('Custom Error fileName = %s , description = %s', 16, -1, @FileName, @Description)
    raiserror('failed to load package returnValue = %d, package = %s', 16, -1, @returnValue, @PackageName)
    return
END
EXEC @returnValue = sp_OAMethod @objPackage, 'SaveToSQLServerAs' , null,
    @NewName = @PackageName, @ServerName = @@ServerName, @Flags = 256
IF @returnValue <> 0
BEGIN
    raiserror('failed to save to SQL server returnValue = %d, package = %s', 16, -1, @returnValue, @PackageName)
    return
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQl Server 2008 does not use DTS pacakages. You should be creating SSIS packages.

Therre is some availablity to work with DTS in SQl Server 2008,m ,but it does not come out of teh box. I would under no circumstances use this to create new DTS pacakages but only to manage exisitng ones until they can be converted to SSIS. Our policy was that every time we had to make a change to a DTS pacakge, we converted it. But the link below may help you find teh toold you need to work with DTS in SQL Server 2008.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143755(v=sql.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143755%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: thanks I have installed the dts package backward compatibility and i can import the package and import it but i cannot create the package using above script. does it mean its not fully backwards compatible?

Comment: Correct, they do not want you to use DTS anymore and they have made it as awkward as possible.  Really, the policy should be to never create a new DTS pacakage on a 2008 instance.

Comment: is there a way we can migrate dts to SSIS easily?

Comment: There is a conversion wizard, but depends on what the DTS task does, not everything converts seamlessly.

Comment: thanks buddy, I will look into how to convert to SSIS package, if you have useful links please post.